# Multidimensional array segfault and 139 (0x8B) return

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, allocation

I'm trying to allocate a multidimensional array to read information from a file and then printing it to check if it is working properly and to get the array information to a 2D array afterwards (not done yet). But for some reason it gives me segfault and returns 139 (0x8B), and when I run it and when I try to debug it it prints everything but at the end it says that it cannot open file: lib-start.c. Thank you in advance!

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <ctype.h>

    int ***getFileLoad (char *nomeFicheiro);
    int ***InitArray (int ***array, int cells);
    void freeArray(int ***array, int cells);

    int main () {

    int ***intArray=NULL, intCells;
    char strNome[10], *p2String=NULL;

    printf("Nome ficheiro: ");
    scanf("%s", strNome);

    p2String=strNome;

    intArray=getFileLoad(p2String);

    intCells=intArray[1][0][0];   /*intCells+2 -> nr of lines to read from the file*/

    freeArray(intArray, intCells);

    return 0;
}

int ***getFileLoad (char *nomeFicheiro) {

    char strLines[5], strColumns[5], strCells[5], strTemp[3];
    int i=0, j=0, k=0, b=2, lines=0, columns=0, cells=0, intTemp=0;
    int ***array=NULL;
    FILE *ficheiro=NULL;

    ficheiro=fopen(nomeFicheiro, "r");   /*open file*/

    if (ficheiro==NULL) {
        printf("Erro ao abrir o ficheiro!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fscanf(ficheiro, "%s %s %s", strLines, strColumns, strCells);

    if ((lines=atoi(strLines))<=0) {    
        printf("Invalid nr of lines!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((columns=atoi(strColumns))<=0) {      
        printf("Invalid nr of columns!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((cells=atoi(strCells))<=0) {
        printf("Invalid nr of cells!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    array=InitArray(&array, cells);

    array[0][0][0]=lines;
    array[0][1][0]=columns;
    array[1][0][0]=cells;


    for (i=2 ; i<cells+b ; i++) {       /*nr of lines to read*/
        for (j=0 ; j<1 ; j++) {         /*last value*/
            for (k=0 ; k<4 ; k++) {     /*middle value*/
                if (k==3) {             /*check if there is something else that I don't want on the Array*/
                    intTemp=fgetc(ficheiro);
                    if (intTemp=='\n' || intTemp==EOF) {
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        while(intTemp!='\n' || intTemp!=EOF) {
                            intTemp=fgetc(ficheiro);
                            if (intTemp=='\n' || intTemp==EOF) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    fscanf(ficheiro, "%s", strTemp);

                    if (isdigit(strTemp)) {
                        intTemp=atoi(strTemp);
                        if (k==0) {             /*accepts lines between 1->lines*/
                            if (!(intTemp>=1 && intTemp<lines)) {
                                printf("Invalid values!\n");
                                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                            } else {
                            array[i][k][j]=intTemp;
                            }
                        } else if (k==1) {      /*accepts columns between 1->columns*/
                            if (!(intTemp>=1 && intTemp<columns)) {
                                printf("Invalid values!\n");
                                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                            } else {
                            array[i][k][j]=intTemp;
                            }
                        } else if (k==2) {      /*accepts cells with values between 0->2*/
                            if (!(intTemp>=0 && intTemp<3)) {
                                printf("Invalid values!\n");
                                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                            } else {
                            array[i][k-1][j+1]=intTemp;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    intTemp=fgetc(ficheiro);   /*checking for EOF*/

    if (intTemp!=EOF) {
        printf("EOF not detected!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fclose(ficheiro);

    return array;
}

int ***InitArray (int ***array, int cells) {

    int b=2, i=0, j=0, k=0 , l=0;

    array=(int ***)malloc((cells+b)* sizeof(int**));    /*allocating 3D array*/

    if (array==NULL) {
        printf("Not enough memory!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for(i=0 ; i<cells+b ; i++) {
        (array)[i]=(int **)malloc(b* sizeof(int*));

        if ((array)[i]==NULL) {
            printf("Not enough memory!\n");
            for (j=0 ; j<i ; j++) {
                free((array)[j]);
            }
            free(array);
            array=NULL;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }


        for (j=0 ; j<b ; j++) {
            (array)[i][j]=(int*)malloc(b*sizeof(int));

            if ((array)[i][j]==NULL) {
            printf("Not enough memory!\n");
            for (k=0 ; k<i ; k++) {
                for (l=0 ; l<j ; l++) {
                    free((array)[k][l]);
                }
            }
            free(array);
            array=NULL;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }

    return array;
}

void freeArray(int ***array, int cells) {

    int i, j, b=2;

    for (i=0 ; i<cells+b ; i++) {
        for (j=0 ; j<b ; j++) {
            free((array)[i][j]);
        }
        free((array)[i]);
    }
    free(array);
    array=NULL;

}
```

File example:

```
22 40
4
1 2 1
1 3 1
1 4 1
1 5 1
```

Comment: `intArray=getFileLoad(p2String);` huh? an `int` returns to `int ***`?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @SouravGhosh, my bad... uptading it

Comment: @RSahu, what do you mean?

Comment: If you want to return an array of ints, use `int *` instead of `int ***`. I'm not even sure what that last one returns. A pointer to a pointer to a pointer to an int?

Comment: @stanpines nothing wrong with `int***`. He want a 3D array, and it is the right syntax for it.

Comment: @Slyer could you give paste the file this program has to work on?

Comment: @Slyer, follow the link.

Comment: @DavideSpataro, posted a file example above

Comment: Davide sorry! I guess I skimmed the code XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program works fine on my system: **Linux Fedora 22 g++ 5.1.1**
No **SEGFAULT**.

I also checked for memory leak and invalid memory access using ***valgrind***

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all ./StackQuestion
```

(suppressed: 0 from 0)

```
==6904== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6904==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6904==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6904==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6904==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==6904==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6904== 
==6904== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6904== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts
```

that states that no invalid access have been made and there is just one unharmful memory leak (unharmful because the operating system will reclain that memory correctly on process termination).

Regarding *lib_start* my guess is that you set up a breakpoint in GDB or you are trying to debug some functions that are basically non-debugable as read() or other function that read/write on files. These function require kernel help for doing this kind of thing (which clearly GDB cannot debug).

I guess we requires more info to reproduce the strange behavior, as g++ verion, OS, and the file you pass to the program.

Comment: Got it to work now! Used Valgrind as you did and it gave me an error on isdigit(strTemp).
Thanks man!

Comment: oh but I tough it was obvious that were 2 errors. isdigit should have been used with stoi and a parameter of initarray is wrong. glad it helped. Please mark the question as answered.